# TouchUtils.dragViewToX will only scroll in one direction

Tags: android, android-testing

I can easily use the following code to scroll the view to the left using

```
TouchUtils.dragViewToX(this, myView, Gravity.LEFT, -1000);
```

It will even just sit there for a second if it can't scroll anymore, like it's still trying to, which is the expected behavior, so the contents of the view shouldn't be the issue.

But if I do the opposite, it acts as though it's not even there.

```
TouchUtils.dragViewToX(this, myView, Gravity.LEFT, 1000);
```

It doesn't even pause for a second to simulate the dragging like the other one will no matter what. It even returns the propper pixel value for distance covered! Why will it only listen to this function when it's supplied with a negative value? Why will it not drag in the opposite direction?
It's not even a positive/negative issue, it will scroll to the left if I supply a positive value and a different Gravity (like RIGHT or END), but no matter what it won't scroll to the right.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, dragViewToX will try to drag the view you specify to the X-coordinate you specify.
2. The Gravity field specifies which part of the view is to be dragged.

So I'd suggest you use the rect values rather that using hard coded coordinates so that the test will work independent of the  device specification. Here's a sample code.

```
View view = sListView.findViewById(R.id.foo);
Rect rect = new Rect();
view.getHitRect(rect);
TouchUtils.dragViewToX(this, view, Gravity.CENTER, rect.left); // To drag left. Make sure the view is to the right of rect.left
TouchUtils.dragViewToX(this, view, Gravity.CENTER, rect.right); // To drag left. Make sure the view is to the left of rect.right
```

The only thing that is wrong with your code is that the value 1000 is already out of the screen and therefore there is no where to drag to :)